# WM_LBUTTONUP message only working as a double click

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a `ListView` Control with a `LVS_REPORT` style set. The thing I want is that when I click the row of an item, doesn't matter where it is, even if it's above a subitem, the item gets selected. Currently, the `ListView` only detects clicks over the first column (item) to make the selection.

To do this, I tried to handle the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message, so when the user releases the left mouse button on the row rectangle, it selects the corresponding item. It could work, but currently it needs a double click to do the selection.

This is the code that goes in the subclass window procedure:

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    long x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    long y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    RECT rc{};

    Message("btn up"); // message box that shows when the left button is released

    for (auto& item : lst->m_items)
    {
        ListView_GetItemRect(lst->handle(), item->index, &rc, LVIR_BOUNDS);
        POINTS p;

        if (PtInRect(&rc, { x, y })) // checks if clicked point is inside the item rect
        {
            ListView_SetItemState(lst->m_hwnd, item->index, LVIS_SELECTED, 7);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The same code (except the loop part) I put inside an Edit subclass procedure and the Main Window subclass procedure. Both work as intended, that is, when a hit a single click, it shows a message.

Is there a workaround for this? Couldn't find any style to achieve this objective, either. What could be causing this issue? I thought, for some reason, that either some other window could be above the `ListView` and that could be stopping it to receive new clicks or also it could be sending the click first to the parent window. These are not the case: 1) the control is not behind any other window; 2) if this was the case, the program would show a `MessageBox` with the message specified in the procedure, which doesn't happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` extended style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/extended-list-view-styles)?

Comment: Nice! Can't figure out what was the issue with handling the WM_LBUTTONUP, but that's exactly the style I needed. Don't know how I missed that - probably have been reading too much of this awful win docs hehe Thanks a lot